# Set a GameObject in front of an image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble setting an image behind a gameobject in unity. I saw a lot of similar questions but none solved my problem. So basically I need to have the image as a child of the object to be able to do what I'm to do. I added an image of my unity view.

[image]

Comment: If you want a UI Image behind a World GameObject, you should use [World Space Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html)

Comment: But that won't work if I put the UI as a child of the GameObject, that's my point

Comment: Can't you just change the order of the image and gameobject, so one gets behind the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely cheat this by using multiple cameras and layers. Set your container GameObject to its one layer (say "GameObjectLayer",) and set your image's GameObject to another layer (say "ImageUILayer".)

Then, create two cameras, and set the following properties:

```
Camera 1:
  Depth = 0
  Culling Mask = "GameObjectLayer"
  Clear Flags & Background = (whatever you want the main camera background to be)

Camera 2:
  Depth = 1
  Culling Mask = "ImageUILayer"
  Clear Flags = Depth only (this keeps the camera from drawing a background at all)
```

Each camera renders in turn, starting with the lowest depth and working up from there. Thus, Camera 1 renders everything in the "GameObjectLayer" first; then, Camera 2 renders everything in the "ImageUILayer" over top of that.

It's an extremely useful workaround when you're trying to mix 2D sprites with 3D objects, and it will *never* give you any flicker or other z-positioning weirdness, because the cameras each render all their layers in turn.

You can use more than two cameras if you need more than two layers of 3D/2D objects; I'm currently using a total of seven cameras with no ill effects.

Answer (score 0):

in your case I suggest you use the(right click and choose)>2D > Sprites and put the sprites behind of the Gameobject